# Как пересоздать активити с данными при смене тёмной темы?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity

По нажатию на кнопку во view model у меня меняется тема:

```
    R.id.appBarActionTheme -> {
        val nightMode = preferenceRepository.nightMode
        preferenceRepository.nightMode = appContext.switchDarkLightMode(nightMode)
    }
```

Вот сам метод:

```
fun Context.switchDarkLightMode(currentMode: Int): Int {
    val newMode = when (currentMode) {
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        else -> {
            if (this.isDarkThemeSet()) AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        }
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(newMode)
    return newMode
}
```

И загвоздка в том, что при вызове данного метода `setDefaultNightMode`, пересоздаётся активити, примерно как при повороте экрана.
И у меня перезапускается приложение, которое в свою очередь сразу отобрает блокировку.

Чтобы снять блокировку я передавал в Intent данные которые после обрабатывал и мог пропустить экран блокировки, делал я примерно следующим образом

```
fun restartLockableActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, this.javaClass).apply { putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true) })
    finish()
}
```

Но как сейчас обойти этот момент я не знаю и не уверен что сэтить Intent хороший вариант, к тому же он у меня не срабатывает
Если я добавлю что то подобное в функцию расшерения `switchDarkLightMode` следующие строки:

```
val intent = Intent(this, this.javaClass).apply { putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true) }
(this as? Activity)?.intent = intent
```

**ВОПРОС**:
Как переключать тему без перегрузки activity или перегружать так чтобы можно было засунуть данные Intent'а?

Comment: Пробовали ли вы установить атрибут [`launchMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#launchMode) в манифесте? Не думаю, что это единственное (и **верное** ли?) решение

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, без полной картины архитектуры приложения сложно дать однозначный ответ. Для сохранения данных есть довольно много способов.
Если вы используете **MVVM** в сочетании с **LiveData** могу дать своё решение.
Что насчет интентов для передачи информации, то это далеко не лучший вариант конечно же. Для упрощения навигации могу порекомендовать взглянуть на **Navigation Component**, там довольно простая реализация.

Либо еще как вариант, для восстановления состояния активности/фрагмента по классике можно использовать `onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)` или `setRetainInstance(true);`

Возможно моё решение поможет, либо хотя бы натолкнёт на правильные мысли.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
private lateinit var viewModel: ExampleViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //инициализируем слушатель для кнопки смены темы
    switch_theme_mode.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.switchTheme()
    }
        initViewModel()
}
}
private fun initViewModel(){
     viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ExampleViewModel::class.java)
    )
    viewModel.getTheme().observe(this, Observer { updateTheme(it) })
}

private fun updateTheme(mode: Int) {
    delegate.setLocalNightMode(mode)

}
```

ExampleViewModel.kt

```
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val repository: PreferencesRepository = PreferencesRepository
private val appTheme = MutableLiveData<Int>()
init {
    appTheme.value = repository.getAppTheme()
}
fun getTheme(): LiveData<Int> = appTheme
fun switchTheme() {
    if (appTheme.value == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
        appTheme.value = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
    } else {
        appTheme.value = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
    }

    repository.saveAppTheme(appTheme.value!!)
    }
}
```

PreferencesRepository.kt

```
object PreferencesRepository {
private const val  APP_THEME = "APP_THEME"

private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
    val ctx = App.applicationContext()
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)
}
fun saveAppTheme(theme: Int) {
   putValue(APP_THEME to theme)
}
fun getAppTheme() : Int = prefs.getInt(APP_THEME, 
AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

App.kt (не забудьте указать имя и тему в манифесте)

```
class App : Application() {
companion object{
    private var instance:App? = null

    fun applicationContext(): Context {
        return instance!!.applicationContext
    }
}

init {
    instance = this
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    PreferencesRepository.getAppTheme().also {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(it)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: метод `updateTheme` у вас что делает?

Comment: @Morozov  Упс, прозевал как-то, видимо при редактировании случайно удалил. Вернул код. Можно сразу через проперти delegate.localNightMode = mode